# Bootstrap Datepicker not Working on Server but works locally

Tags: javascript, .net, bootstrap-4

My Datepicker in modal does not work on server but works properly on localhost. Below is my html and js code:

Html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateAppointmentModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Create Appointment</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="CreateAppointmentBody">

        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).on("click", ".AppointmentItem", function () {

        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        idOfCust = row.find("td:first-child").text();

        var url = '/Home/Create_AppointmentAdmin';
        console.log(url);

        $('#CreateAppointmentModal').modal('show');
        $('#CreateAppointmentBody').load(url);

    });

    $('#CreateAppointmentModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        console.log('Entered');
        $('.daterangepicker').css('z-index', '1600');
        $(".daterangepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            //onSelect: PopulateDropDown,
            minDate: 0
        });
    });
```

Modal Body:

```
<div class="alert" role="alert" id="alertBox" style="display:none">

</div>
<div class="row">



    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Create_AppointmentAdmin" autocomplete="off">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="Userid" type="hidden" id="CustId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AppointmentDay" class="control-label">Appointment Day</label>
                <input asp-for="AppointmentDay" class="form-control daterangepicker" id="Calendar_Admin" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="AppointmentDay" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AppointmentTime" class="control-label">Appointment Time</label>

                <select asp-for="AppointmentTime" class="form-control" id="AppointmentTime">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AppointmentTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label">Comments</label>
                <input asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" id="Comment" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" value="Create Appointment" class="btn btn-success" id="CreateAppointmentAdmin" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have tried multiple solutions availabe here but none seem to work.

Is there some mistake that I am doing? The same code seems to work fine on server when it is a full fledged page.

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: please check in browser console might be you have got error

Comment: Also in the above example of code model body is missing kindly add with caledar input code.

Comment: @MohsinMarui Browser Console does not give any error and added Modal Body code. Thanks :)

Comment: Please add this css and check `.daterangepicker{ z-index:99999 !important; }` OR `#Calendar_Admin{ z-index:99999 !important; }`

Comment: Tried Both, didn't work

Comment: can you please send the URL?